# XSS javascript, exploit check

Tags: javascript, xss

I am currently working on a page where I need the user to input several variables which when submitted are then displayed throughout the page.

Problem is, it needs to be 100% secure code and whilst I'm ok using PDO/mysql etc javascript is not something I'm very fluent in.

At the moment, I have the following:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function showInput() {
    document.getElementById('var1').innerText = 
                document.getElementById("user_var1").value;
    document.getElementById('var2').innerText = 
                document.getElementById("user_var2").value;
}
</script>
```

with the html

```
<form>
     your variable 1 is = <input type="text" name="message" id="user_var1"><br />
     your variable 2 is = <input type="text" name="message" id="user_var2"><br />
</form>
 <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();">
  <p>var1 = <span id='var1'></span></p>
  <p>var2 = <span id='var2'></span></p>
```

From what I can tell, using ".innerText" should stop any html etc being used and I have tested with

```
<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>
```

which results in the above just being printed as is (not run).

e.g.

```
your variable 1 is = <script>alert(document.cookie);</script>
```

Is there anything else you would recommend doing to make sure it is secure (XSS or otherwise)? Only characters that should need to be entered are / and A-Z 0-9

Thanks in advance :)

## edit

Just to clarify, the only code is what is above, the page is not pulling data from a database etc (what you see above is virtually the full php page, just missing the html head body tags etc).

Comment: what do you mean with `100% secure code` JS cannot be secure, it's running on a machine, you have no control over.  the easiest "attacks" here would be to overwrite `showInput` with whatever I want, or if I just want to disable that, remove the id's from the nodes, mess with the button, or change the clickhandler on the button. And that's just getting started, so what do you mean with secure?

Comment: Admittingly 100% secure was probably the wrong term to use. By this, I mean the user would not be able to inject or add anything to the hosting or use it to traverse to another directory (e.g. using ../../../). e.g. with some pages that use mysql I had to change to PDO etc to stop injections.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, the user just has to press F12 in the browser and can execute pretty much *anything he/she wants* in your page. Like `showInput = null;` or `document.getElementById('var1').innerHTML = "...whatever..."` or ... you have (almost) no control whatsoever.

Comment: So inspect element etc mean you have no control, how would you suggest  letting a user add a variable to a html page safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* no vulnerability here (please read before downvote).

> Just to clarify, the only code is what is above, the page is not
>   pulling data from a database etc (what you see above is virtually the
>   full php page, just missing the html head body tags etc).

Therefore the following two fields cannot be populated by anything other than the current user:

```
<input type="text" name="message" id="user_var1">
<input type="text" name="message" id="user_var2">
```

because there is no code present that populates these two fields.

The two DOM elements that are populated by code are as follows:

```
<span id='var1'></span>
<span id='var2'></span>
```

The code which does this is

```
document.getElementById('var1').innerText = 
                document.getElementById("user_var1").value;
document.getElementById('var2').innerText = 
                document.getElementById("user_var2").value;
```

It is using the non-standard [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) rather than [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), however `innerText` will set the text content rather than HTML content, preventing the browser from rendering any tags or script.

However, even if it was setting the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property instead, all the user could do is attack themselves (just the same as they would opening up developer tools within their browser).

However, in the interests of correct functional behaviour and internet standards, I would use `textContent` rather than `innerText` or `innerHTML`.

Note that

```
<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>
```

would not work anyway, it would have to be

```
<svg onload="alert(document.cookie)" />
```

or similar. HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted via innerHTML should not execute.

Comment: :) Thank you for your input. Was really starting to get confused as how it could be secure if editing via "inspect element" was a security risk (since its client side).

Comment: Please note that this answer is partly incorrect. While the code in the question is indeed not vulnerable, it would be if it used innerHTML. From an XSS point of view, it doesn't matter much _how_ you can inject javascript. If it is possible, the page is vulnerable. You can argue that the risk is smaller (it is indeed), but it is vulnerable to DOM XSS nonetheless. Just for an example attack for such a scenario: a user can enter something in a field that gets copied to the page dom, just like the above but with innerHTML. What if a colleague "helpfully" sent over a piece of data to be inserted?

Answer (score 2):

Just based on what you're doing above you're not going to have XSS. `innerText` will do proper escaping.

To have your site be 100% secure is a tall order. Some of the things I'd look at are running your site over [HTTPS](https://letsencrypt.org/) with [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security) to prevent a network level adversary tampering with the site, [parameterizing your SQL queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet), adding [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) tokens as necessary on form submission.

Specifically regarding XSS, one of the most common ways people get XSS'd is because they perform insecure DOM manipulation. If you're concerned about security I'd highly recommend porting your JS to [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) as you're manipulating a "virtual DOM", which allows React to perform context sensitive escaping. It also takes the burden off of the developer from having to do proper escaping.

One quick security win is adding a [CSP policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP) to your site and setting the `script-src` directive to `self`. A CSP policy establishes the context in which certain content can run on your site. So if for example, you have `script-src` set to `self` (meaning your JS is loaded in the `src` attribute of a `<script>` tag pointing to the same domain as where the HTML is served, and not inline on the page) if someone does XSS it will (most likely*) not run.

These are just some examples of different security solutions available to you and a brief intro to security-in-depth practices. I'm glad you're taking security seriously!

*There are some circumstances (if you're dynamically generating your scripts for example) in which their code could run.

Comment: Thanks for this. As time will be a factor on this and it is obvious I'm going to need to do a lot of reading. One option I was pondering about doing was using an iframe and having the above code on a different hosting page + domain. From what I can see, any exploit then should be stuck to the new hosting package (thus limiting damage).

Comment: Absolutely, so that's making use of the Same origin policy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) as a defense, which is good (for the most part) so long as there's no sensitive information on the iframe's domain

Comment: Thanks :) Basically the new hosting package would just have the above code (nothing else).

Comment: Yep, with security, there's always ways you can further lock something down. It's virtually impossible to be 100% secure, but for your purposes what you've proposed should be just fine :)

Comment: Thanks, I've marked up and ticked by as I'm still new I don't think I have the rep to make it count yet :)

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, and not the accepted one.