# Using ctype_digit($_GET['x']) with $_GET['x'] > 0?

Tags: php, security, xss

Is there any point to use `ctype_digit()` with a `comparison operator` in `if statement` like this

```
if ($_GET['x'] > 0 && ctype_digit($_GET['x'])) {
    echo 'It is a Number';
}
```

Comment: Why both? If the first sentence returns true it automatically means it's a number, isn't it?

Comment: there's a much simpler way to do this; what's the context of this? edit: and what does this have to do with [`security`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security)?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I remember being attacked by `XSS` attack using different `unicode` like `x3346`, So I feared if that possible on `> 0` if `0` has a `Unicode` with letters and has been accepted.

Comment: @PedroFaria99 No, it could be a string containing a float or scientific notation.

Comment: @Toleo have you gone through these yet? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466104/xss-javascript-exploit-check --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521743/how-to-exploit-http-header-xss-vulnerability --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414962/protection-against-xss-exploits ?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, But didn't know from them the risk that ishegg mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (emphasis mine):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then **each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically**.

So if `x` is a "non numeric string", your first check will fail and short-circuit the conditions, making `ctype_digit()` redundant in this situation.

However, be careful with this conversion. `123abc` for example will return true for your first check (since for the comparison, `123` is used), so depending on how strict this is, maybe do a thorough check instead.

```
$s = "123abc";
var_dump($s > 0); // true
```

Comment: Oh, Didn't know about `1a > 0 = true` at all.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, it's possible if you want to make sure the input is a decimal number, and greater than zero

Comment: TBH, this answer is more of a comment and lacks detail and it needs to be improved. It's considered as being VLQ (very low-quality).